# Opacity for MapView and ItemizedOverlay

Tags: opacity, itemizedoverlay, android-mapview

Is there a way where I can darken the MapView but not affect the overlay item?
I'd like to make my overlay item really bright as compared to the google map, so that users are more inclined to just tap on the item rather than interacting with the map.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is hard thing to do, but you can do something else to attract the user (I believe it is better), use [AnimationDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html) , you can create multiple images in some sort of way that it can attract the user and use the function addFrame(Drawable d, int duration) to add the images. Good luck